# How can I replace a substring of text within an anchor tag on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a tag:

```
<a class="showrepbut" href="javascript:void(0);" data-fpost="rbox-@post.NatForumPostID">Hide 2 replies</a>
```

and I would like to do something like this:

```
$('.showrepbut').click(function () {
   if ($(this).text().includes('Show')) {
       $(this).replace(/Show/g, 'Hide');
   }
   else if ($(this).text().includes('Hide')) {
       $(this).replace(/Hide/g, 'Show');
   }
});
```

So that the show is replaced with hide when show is present and visa versa. Obviously the above doesn't work.  I've tried .includes, :contains .innerHTML.indexOf etc and nothing seems to work.

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/hshzp4rb/)

Can anyone clarify how I should approach this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fine updated code below:

```
$('.showrepbut').click(function () {
    if ($(this).text().includes('Show')) {
        $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/Show/g, 'Hide'));
    }
    else if ($(this).text().includes('Hide')) {
        $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/Hide/g, 'Show'));
    }
});
```

for working fiddle demo [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/hshzp4rb/3/)

Comment: This was the first answer that produced the correct result so I will mark it as the answer when I am able.

Comment: TBH, you shouldn't mix `.html()` and `.text()` - either get the text and set it using `.text(value)` or get it as html.

Comment: Your fiddle uses `.text` but the answer uses `.html`, which makes it vulnerable to xss if the original text was properly escaped.

Answer (score 4):

You need to replace `$(this).text()` instead of `$(this)`.

```
 $('.showrepbut').click(function () {
            if ($(this).text().includes('Show')) {
                $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/Show/g, 'Hide'));
            }
            else if ($(this).text().includes('Hide')) {
                $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/Hide/g, 'Show'));
            }
        });
```

Comment: Have a closer look...  you're replacing the text inside the text, but doing nothing with it.

Comment: giving you a +1 because you're the original poster of the answer and as I can see, all of them copied it from you...

Comment: @ТодорИванов this was the first answer, but had an omission (see edit).  and the other answers appeared before the edit.  The answer is so trivial (to experienced developers, not meant to insult learners, trivial as in small) that all the answers will be the same or close enough, not copied and the post times show they are all around the same time. (not a good reason for not giving +1 though as it's a good answer).

Answer (score 1):

This should do

```
$('.showrepbut').click(function () {                        
            var txt = $(this).text().indexOf("Show")> -1 ? "Hide" : "Show";
            $(this).text(txt+ "2 replies");
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hshzp4rb/5/

Comment: My issue with this answer is that it has the text from the tag actually present in the jquery itself which isn't practical for me.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$('.showrepbut').click(function () {
  var text = $(this).text();
  if ($(this).text().includes('Show')) {
    $(this).text(text.replace(/Show/g, 'Hide'));
  }
  else if ($(this).text().includes('Hide')) {
    $(this).text(text.replace(/Hide/g, 'Show'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="showrepbut" href="javascript:void(0);" data-fpost="rbox-@post.NatForumPostID">Hide 2 replies</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works like that ^^

```js
$('.showrepbut').click(function () {
    if ($(this).text().includes('Show')) {
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace('Show', 'Hide'));
    }
    else if ($(this).text().includes('Hide')) {
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace('Hide', 'Show'));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a class="showrepbut" href="javascript:void(0);" data-fpost="rbox-@post.NatForumPostID">Hide 2 replies</a>
```